# How to enable logging in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm getting this error from a simple `testcafe` command

```
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error.

undefined

Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

and have a zero clue with what's the problem. I'm tried to run `testcafe --dev` as well, but it didn't help

Comment: What are your tests? Have you tried to simplify them to find a place that causes this error?

Comment: TS-files, compilation works fine. the primitive test works also fine, but even a single test fails with that error.

Answer (score 1):

After some days of debugging I've narrowed it down to the thing that Testcafe don't show you exception text if it was thrown without `Error` instance.

For example, his code fails cryptically with `undefined` as a message

```
throw 'Param is missed`
```

This code fails with the expected message `Param is missed` and a stack trace

```
throw new Error('Param is missed`)
```

But my initial question is still valid.
I still don't know how debug it properly to find source of problem faster.

Comment: This behavior looks like a bug. I suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe GitHub repository. Please also send a simple project example where the issue is reproduced.